# Twig form_select values from array

Tags: twig

Is it possible to iterate through an array to generate the values that populate a select box, rather than hard-coding them in the template?

I'm passing an array of values to the template that I would like available in the select box, but I'm not sure how to go about iterating through it.

Here's how I currently have it:

```
{{ form_select('profile_status', {
    'created' : 'Candidate Created',
    'mailed': 'Questionnaire Mailed',
    'personal_info': 'Personal Data Filled Out',
    'survey': 'Survey Completed',
    'primary': 'Waiting for Post-Primary Updates',
    'endorsements': 'Endorsements Completed',
    'essay': 'Essay Completed',
}, candidate.profile_status, {'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'profile-status'})|raw }}
```

What I'm not sure how to do is implement a for-loop within an already existing twig tag to replace the hard-coded list of values.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 4.1